# starts from jnlp but not from dtjava

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My app starts just fine if I download the .jnlp-file and double-click it or load it with javaws from url-to-file.jnlp. But I can not get it to start properly with the dtjava-script.

The following happens:

1. List item
2. Java starts (Java 7 - version 25)
3. The security-dialog shows correctly (the code is signed).
4. Then nothing!  The process simply exits.  No error-messages. No nothing.

I am developing on a Mac. But the same happens on Windows-machines.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try do adjust your application to something simple (like hello world) and check if works. Later add some complex elements to check what exactly cause problem.

Comment: I think we'll need more details. How your set up the deployment script, and what your JNLP contains, for instance. also, does the Java console show up? Make sure you activate it in the java control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The suggestion to try a tiny "hello world" first led me to the idea to try to set the initial-heap-size in the jnlp-file.  This caused the program not to exit on error and I saw that there was an exception related to some reloader code ... which lead me to think that something was causing a failed attempt to load a preloader.

Here is what my code was:

```
dtjava.launch(
    {
        url : jnlp_path,
        params: {
            'key5': 'value 5',
            'key6': 'value 6!' } },
    {
        javafx : '2.2+',
        toolkit: 'swing' },
    {} );
```

The solution was to simply remove `javafx : '2.2+',`

I guess the javafx-param was causing an attempt to first load a non-existent JavaFX preloader.